# How to set consistency level on per-query basis in Java Spring Data Cassandra Reactive Library

Tags: java, cassandra, spring-webflux, spring-data-cassandra

I am using Spring Data Cassandra reactive library in Java and using ReactiveCqlTemplate to query ScyllaDB.

On an application level, we can set by specifying property as below in the application.properties file

spring.data.cassandra.consistency-level=quorum

My question is how do I specify consistency level on a per-query level using ReactiveCqlTemplate? I am using ReactiveCqlTemplate to query my Scylla DB. The code sample is as below:

```
@Autowired
private ReactiveCqlTemplate template;

@Override
public Mono<Template> findTemplate(Channel channel, String id) {
    String query = "select * from task where id = ? and channel = ?";
    
    return template.queryForObject(query,  new RowMapper<Template>() {
        public Template mapRow(Row row, int rowNum) {
          Template template = new Template();
          template.setContent(row.getString("content"));
          template.setMessageType(row.getString("message_type"));
          template.setSource(row.getString("source"));
          template.setSubject(row.getString("subject"));
          template.setTemplateKey(new TemplateKey(row.getString("id"), Channel.fromString(row.getString(("channel")))));
          return template;
        }}, UUID.fromString(id), channel.toString());
}
```

There is an option to set ConsistencyLevel in using the template variable above but that would be for the whole object. I would like to specify on each-query I am shooting to Scylla DB.

Comment: Do not post the code as image, always paste it as text and use formatting in editor.

Comment: Please include *code*, not images of code: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at:

[`ReactiveCqlTemplate.setConsistencyLevel(:ConsistencyLevel)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/3.1.5/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/ReactiveCqlTemplate.html#setConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.ConsistencyLevel-)

And...

[`ReactiveCqlTemplate.setSerialConsistencyLevel(:ConsistencyLevel)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/3.1.5/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/ReactiveCqlTemplate.html#setSerialConsistencyLevel-com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.ConsistencyLevel-)

> NOTE: This will apply to all Statements executed with this template.

If you need finer-grained control per Statement, then I suggest:

[`ReactiveCqlTemplate.execute(:ReactivePreparedStatementCreator)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/3.1.5/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/ReactiveCqlTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactivePreparedStatementCreator-)

Or...

[`ReactiveCqlTemplate.execute(:ReactivePreparedStatementCreator, ReactivePreparedStatementCallback<T>)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/3.1.5/api/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/cql/ReactiveCqlTemplate.html#execute-org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactivePreparedStatementCreator-org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.ReactivePreparedStatementCallback-)

The creator allows you to create the `Statement` however you like.  And, the callback gives you access to the DataStax `Statement` API where you can configure additional settings as needed.

See [`Statement`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.10/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/cql/Statement.html) and [`StatementBuilder`](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/4.10/com/datastax/oss/driver/api/core/cql/StatementBuilder.html).

Comment: Also for reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/issues/1095

Comment: There is a lack of documentation around what you have suggested. Could you please help me with one working example where we are setting consistency level on a per-query basis and CQL getting converted into PreparedStatement as well

please help